# Node.js Restify Refreshing other clients from server

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, restify

I have made a small chat where users can login and write.

The thing is that i want to be able to refresh other users chat window when a new message have been created.

So if Person A writes a message in the chat Person B's chat need to refresh.

I am thinking that i need some sort of connection between the client and server, and that the server needs to send a update about the fact that the chat messages has been updated. And then refresh the window.

I know that i can have the chat window refresh on its on at a timed interval, but i only want to refresh on a file change.

These are the restify versions i am using, and my chat messages are being stored in a .json file
"restify": "^6.3.4",
"restify-cors-middleware": "^1.1.0"

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: WebSockets is what you want. Look for socket.io on NPM. You don't need to refresh the page and you shouldn't.

Comment: I tried looking at socket.io but as far as i understood, it does not work with restify

Comment: @JakeTheDane WebSockets and Restify are really different things. Restify is obviously about rest oriented applications while WebSockets are all about persistent communication. You might want to look into using something like Sails, which comes with sockets built in.